# Change parts of email template

Tags: magento2, email, template

I want to change the email template "New Order (Magento/luma)".

I want to remove the SKU column from order items table, and I think the following line will send me to the file where I must make the changes:

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}`

How do I interpret that line of code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handle name is a xml layout file name.
In your case, you can find the sales_email_order_items
handle file here:

`module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml`

You can extend or override it.

Comment: Thank you very much!